# How to add formatting to javascript's number display globally

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I have a number and I want to add comma to it when it's displayed as a string.

I can add comma to the number like this:

```
function numberWithCommas(value) {
  return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

But I don't want to call a method on every number that we have to get this.  I want to do something similar to this:

```
Number.prototype.toString = function(radix) {
  return numberWithCommas(this);
}
```

So when I do the following, the right value will show up:

```
var num = 100000;
alert(num); // 100,000
```

Can't get the above to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you call the toString() your going to get an infinite recursive loop between the two function.

Comment: Your method will also add commas to a decimal with more than 3 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a new number function?

```
Number.prototype.withCommas = function(){
    return this.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var n = 1234567;
alert( n.withCommas() );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kyX8x/1/